# Monthly Calendar in Android

Tags: android

I want to make calendar in android in which at top there must be a spinner of months and by clicking on a particular month corresponding calendar should open.By default on starting app current month calendar should be opened with selected date.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: i am not able to customize calendar month wise

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [Custom calendar](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) library.
If you don't want to use library project, just pick up required calendar classes and layout from it. Put it into your project.
It is highly customisable. So you can  then make changes in it's classes as per your requirement.

Comment: i have tried this but this is not what i want i.e. spinner view of months and by clicking on a particular month it's calendar is shown.

Comment: @PayalGulati : You will never find exact code of what you want. You have to customised it as per your requirement. You can add your own spinner view in the .xml file and on item selection, add same code which is set on arrow button click event.